# Center JButtons inside a JPanel in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

I am trying to add `JButton` components to a `JPanel` that I added to a `JScrollPane`. I want that they are vertically aligned. I already found the solution with the `BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)` in the panel, but after I did that the buttons had different widths.

[image: test]

I also would like to add some space between the buttons.

Comment: 1) Create a JPanel using a GridLayout. All buttons will be the same size and  you can define space between the buttons. 2) Create a second panel. The layout manager you use will be based on your requirement. If you want the buttons centered both vertically and horizontally then use a GridBagLayout. If you just want them centered then use a FlowLayout. Add the buttons panel to this panel. Then add this panel to your scroll pane. The point is you can nest panels to achieve a desire layout.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different layout. Grid or GridBag is what you're looking for, although GridBag is overkill for something this simple:

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
panel.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
panel.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
panel.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
```

Comment: The problem is there arent always 3 buttons. There can be more too. and if i set the Rows equal to the amount of buttons the buttons will be smaller and smaller and for that I have the ScrollPane. How am i doing it that i can scroll and the buttons will have a consistent size

Comment: You can set the rows to 0 and it will act how you want.

Comment: When I set the rows to 0, the height gets smaller the more Buttons there are.

Comment: You may see some vertical resizing to the minimum size of the button.  If that's an issue, you may want to consider a `GridBagLayout` with size restrictions.

Comment: *the height gets smaller the more Buttons there are* - which is why you need the wrapper panel as I suggested in my original comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a gridbaglayout , and apply vertical spacers at the button of each button. Also the text in button is not equal to the second and third button dats why it has a different size. So you can adjust it using the preferred size tool

Comment: What do you mean by *"preferred size tool"*? There is a method related to that, but it most often *should not* be used. Layouts are a more robust method to achieve the effect of making components of equal size. They will take into account the preferred size of each component.